# Trigger working intermittently

Tags: apex, trigger

We have a trigger that is working intermittently and we can't work out why.

What it's doing is very simple. Updating a status field on another object.

I don't have much development experience, so instead of trying to mess around the trigger, i thought about creating a scheduled apex class that does the same thing to catch all records.

Can you see any reason why the trigger below wouldn't change the status of all records, even though the criteria is being met?

It may be worth mentioning that this trigger updates well over a thousand records a month, with only a few failing to update.

```
trigger COL_JIS_Set_Status_Closed on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (before      update) {
    system.debug('entering trigger COL_JIS_Set_Status_Closed');
    BMCServiceDesk__Status__c closedstatus = [Select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Status__c where Name = 'Closed' 
                                      and BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = False limit 1];
    system.debug('before forloop '+Trigger.New);

    for (BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c inc : Trigger.New){
        system.debug('INC '+inc);
        system.debug('old map '+Trigger.oldMap.get(inc.id));
        system.debug('old map checkbox '+Trigger.oldMap.get(inc.id).COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c);

        if (inc.COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c == True && Trigger.oldMap.get(inc.id).COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c == False){
            system.debug('if  block status id '+ closedstatus.Id);
            inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c = closedstatus.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If what you say is true "Meets all criteria" then it is most likely other code downstream that is changing it, an error is thrown and possibly caught downstream which caused a rollback, or it did not meet the criteria as you expected. The trigger is pretty basic and seems that very limited errors, if any, could be thrown in it. The only weak spot I see after a quick glance in the query for the status record

Comment: also, this is trigger for update.it would not be fired when record is inserted

Comment: unless a dml event is occurring on `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c`, the trigger will never start; so unless the if statement doesn't get executed for some updated objects (going from false to true), this should execute

Comment: 1.It wouldn't fire unless it is an UPDATE 2.There might be another configuration(like workflow, process) resetting the status or restricting the update.

Comment: For the problem records, is the problem reproducible? If you manually toggle the `COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c` field for those record to false and then back to true can you see the trigger firing in the logs? What else is occurring in the debug logs when set back to true?